# Accessing aws s3 private bucket content

Tags: php, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

How to create signed url to show aws s3 private content using php?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure that answer is in documentation, if you take time to read it : https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-php/

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP documentation for Amazon S3 Pre-Signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html#amazon-s3-pre-signed-url):

> You can authenticate certain types of requests by passing the required information as query-string parameters instead of using the Authorization HTTP header. This is useful for enabling direct third-party browser access to your private Amazon S3 data, without proxying the request. The idea is to construct a "pre-signed" request and encode it as a URL that an end-user's browser can retrieve. Additionally, you can limit a pre-signed request by specifying an expiration time.

Basically, you can programatically generate a URL that permits time-limited access to an Amazon S3 object.